# FooTable is undefined error

Tags: jquery, footable

I am trying to build a fooTable where my table head declarations is on another form and html row fields are on another form. Here is the design,

**pro form**

```
    <table class="footable table" id="L-EGY-TRG-501-00BP_fooTable" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th data-sort-initial="true" data-toggle="true">Employed by</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Sub-Category</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Attendee Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody id="L-EGY-TRG-501-00BP_fooTableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**trg-row form**

```
<table>
    <tr id="yyy" data-losstype="fin-row" data-GUID="L-EGY-TRG-ROW-501-003H">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yyy_EmployedBy" name="yyy_EmployedBy" value=""   >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yyy_Category" name="yyy_Category" value=""   >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yyy_SubCategory" name="yyy_SubCategory" value=""   >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yyy_attendeecount" name="yyy_attendeecount" value=""   >
        </td>


        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-rounded" onClick="#" title="Add Attendee Row">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-rounded removeRowLink" onClick="#" title="Remove Attendee Row">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

This is how I am trying to do using JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        guid="xxxxx"
        prepTable("/pro?openform,guid); //
});
function prepTable(surl,guid){
            $.get( surl, function( data ) {               

        var footable = $(data).find('.footable').footable();

        guid="xxxxx";                     
        buildFooTable(guid,"/trg-row?openform");

            });
}

 funtion buildFooTabl(containerID,surl) {
        $.get( surl, function( data ) {  
            var $row = $(data).find('#yyy');
            var footable = $('#' + containerID + '_fooTable').data('footable');
            var rowid = $row.attr('data-GUID');
            $row.find('[id*=yyy]').each(function() {
                   var id = this.id || "";
                   this.id = id.replace('yyy', rowid)
              });
            $row.find('[name*=yyy]').each(function() {
                var nm = this.name || "";
                    this.name = nm.replace('yyy', rowid)
             });

         $row.attr('id',rowid);
             footable.appendRow($row);
        });
```

But getting error "TypeError: footable is undefined" error at this line however fooTable id is coming correctly.

```
var footable = $('#' + containerID + '_fooTable').data('footable');
```

Comment: There is no such element in DOM with id = 'xxxxx_fooTable'

Comment: @DinoMyte, Yup its there ..Check my edit

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is on this Line:

```
var footable = $('#' + containerID + '_fooTable').data('footable');
```

The problem is that nowhere in your html do you have an attribute like "data-footable".

The jQuery method .data('parm') pulls the value of a data-parm attribute. The parameter is irrelevent. if you have a div like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-mytext="This is my text"></div>
```

And you do this:

```
var mytext = $('#mydiv').data('mytext')
alert(mytext);
```

The alert will say; "This is my text". Because the .data('mytext') function has pulled the value of the data-mytext attribute.

So what are you trying to load into the var footable? if you are trying to get a reference to your table and you have the correct containerID then you just need

```
var footable = $('#' + containerID + '_fooTable');
```

Comment: 1- .footable() is defined in footable.all.min.js which is already referenced in the code
2- I don't see any ref where you need to add data-footable="value" attribute. Can you point me ?
3- when I alert $('#' + containerID+ '_fooTable') it gives me exact id which my table has so don't see any problem here too.

Comment: OK, that code wasn't posted here so I was not aware of it. However the other item is the one you mentioned. When you use the jQuery method $('#selector').data('footable') you are saying "In the DOM find the item with ID="selector" and give me the value of the attribute 'data-footable="value"' I did not see anywhere in your code that you posted that had an attribute 'data-footable'

Comment: I don't know if I have to set data-footable="value" somewhere in html. Would you tell me where I have to put ? I don't see anything as such in footable documentation.

Comment: You are missing my point. You are using ".data('footable')" in your code. What that does is pull the value of the attribute "data-footable". Since you don't have anything with that attribute, .data('footable') is not going to do anything. See this fiddle for an explanation of how the jQuery ".data()" function works: http://jsfiddle.net/a92ao7r8/